# Change variable type mysteriously

Tags: vba, variables, types

I have a sub with a variant variable set up that changes its type midway for now apparent reason.

I have the variables declared at the beginning of the procedure:

```
 Dim acsp As Variant 
 Dim oldmaster As Variant 
 Dim acontacts As Variant
 Dim avp As Variant
 Dim acctst As Variant 
 Dim ashipto As Variant 
 Dim abillto As Variant
 Dim found, found1, found2 As Boolean

 acsp = Sheet6.UsedRange.Value2 
 acontacts = Sheet5.UsedRange.Value2 
 avp  = Sheet9.UsedRange.Value2 
 acctst = Sheet20.UsedRange.Value2 
 ashipto = Sheet11.UsedRange.Value 
 abillto = Sheet15.UsedRange.Value
```

The code runs and based on an IF condition it might call this code (inside the same sub):

```
 c = UBound(acsp) + 1   
 shipto = Trim(UCase(acctst(aa, 27)))  
 billto = Trim(UCase(acctst(aa, 38)))
 shiptofound = False   
 For shiptorow = 2 To UBound(ashipto)
  ashipto1 = Trim(UCase(ashipto(shiptorow, 2)))   
  If ashipto1 = shipto  Then
     shiptofound = True
     Exit For    
  End If
 Next shiptorow
```

Up until the shiptofound=False line the abillto variant is shown as variant/variant (1 to 677, 1 to 18) which is correct.
But as soon it runs the line For shiptorow = 2 To UBound(ashipto) then the abillto variant changes to a type variant/long with a value of 2?
At no point prior to this code abillto is used in the code.

Why does VBA do this?

Comment: `Dim found, found1, found2 As Boolean` is the same as `Dim found As Variant, found1 As Variant, found2 As Boolean` and *not* `Dim found As Boolean, found1 As Boolean, found2 As Boolean`. In any event -- if you care so much about variable type, why all those variants?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. There is probably something going on here that involves code that you have not shown.

Comment: I doubt your problem description. There must be something that you are not seeing. Arrays don't spontaneously change into longs. Three questions: 1) Are you using `Option Explicit`? 2) Are you using event handlers? 3) Are you using variables defined outside of any sub? Mysterious bugs can happen when an event handler changes a public variable, and these bugs can be harder to spot if `Option Explicit` isn't being used, since a misspelling can cause you to create new variables without realizing and thus confuse a variable you intentionally defined and a variable that you inadvertently created.

Comment: To start debugging, place `Option Explicit` in the top of every code module (and enforce the decision once and for all in the future by enabling "Require Variable Declaration" in the editor options) and add declarations until the code cleanly compiles. That might turn up something interesting. Or maybe not.

Comment: I dont have variables set up outside the sub and  Im not using the Option explicit.

And no Event Handlers are used, just basic vba.
I am using the variant arrays to create arrays for different sheets so that I can collect different info from different sheets.
In this sub the variant abillto is not used at all until that part of the code.
And I did search for that name to make sure I didnt use it as a Long.

I also did not declare all the variables that I use in this sub like the aa and the booleans shiptofound, billtofound, etc
Could that be the issue somehow?

Comment: The mystery part of this is that I ran the code line by line (F8) observing the variant in the watch window and it only changes when it runs that For Line.

Comment: Start by adding `Option Explicit` and declaring all your variables.

Comment: If there is really no explanation in your code about why `abillto` is changing from a large array to a single long, your VBA project might be corrupt. Taking your problem description at face value, `shipto` and `abillto` seem to be sharing memory even though they are different variables. As an experiment, if that `for loop` is changed to start at 3 (rather than 2) is the mysterious change of `abillto` to the value 3?  Sometimes exporting modules, deleting them, and then reimporting them can fix corrupt projects.

Comment: You might be right. After a night sleep it is working fine today.
The thing is that yesterday I did close and open Excel several times to see if it would work.
The joys of Excel vba bugs I suppose. :)
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm glad that it is working now. Please consider deleting this question since it is unanswerable.